# Is it possible to uncheck “Reopen windows when logging back in” by default?

Tags: macos, osx-lion

It is possible to [disable the “Reopen windows when logging back in”](http://osxdaily.com/2011/08/25/disable-reopen-windows-when-logging-back-in-in-mac-os-x-lion-completely/) option, but is it possible to just make it unchecked by default? I have OS X Lion.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides completely removing it, as you linked, there is currently **no way of unchecking the box by default**.

An option to get around this is to use a keyboard shortcut, which completely skips the dialog box, and will shutdown normally. It acts as though you unchecked the box.

<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Eject</kbd>

Press all those together.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is possible, check out [this post](http://techblog.willshouse.com/2012/01/15/disable-reopen-windows-when-logging-back-in-by-default-os-x-lion/) with instructions for   adding a LoginHook to override restored windows.

Comment: did you see the link?